# How to consume SOAP web service in Spring?

Tags: spring, jaxb, soap-client

I am working in Java first time using eclipse. I need to consume SOAP xml webservice in Java. I have wsdl and xsd schemas for the service. I have created the JASXB classes for the schema.
I created a ServiceUtilty class that contains the Request and Response Objects. I am not sure if this is the correct approach. How to add header in the request?

```java
import com.service.jaxb.provider.finddoc._2015.FindDocRequestType;
import com.service.jaxb.provider.finddoc._2015.FindDocResponseType;
public class testing {
    private FindDocRequestType getFindDocResponseType()
    {
        FindDocRequestType findDocResponseType = new FindDocRequestType();
        String Desc= findDocResponseType.getInfo().getFindDocOutputList().get(0).getDescr();
        return findDocResponseType;
    }
    
    private FindDocRequestType getFindDocRequestType(String DocNo, string docId)
    {
        FindDocRequestType findDocRequestType = new FindDocRequestType();
        findDocResponseType.setversion((short)12);      
        if(DocNo != null)
        {
            findDocRequestType.setDocNo(DocNo);         
        }
        else if (docId != null)
        {
            findDocRequestType.setdocId(docId);
        }       
        return findDocRequestType;
    }   
}
```

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:ns=http://service.bi.com/entity/message/2003/ xmlns:ns1=http://service.bi.com/provider/bi/biService/findBIDoc/2003/>
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns:BIContext>
          <messageId>89</messageId>
          <creationTimestamp>2018-07-27T03:56:56.449Z</creationTimestamp>
          <hostName>localhost</hostName>       
      </ns:BIContext>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:findBIDocRequest>
         <ns:Version>13</ns:Version>
         <docNumber>789999</docNumber>
         <userId>test</userId>
         <docId>88</docId>
        </ns1:findBIDocRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please let me know how to add header in the request. how to create a soap service? thanks